# Unable to insert html form data into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a beginner in php(& mysql).I am trying to insert form data into my database.But it does not       work.Clicking on the 'Register' button on User_info.php page just displays a link to my home page.

**Sign Up.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<title>Details</title>
</head> 
<body bgColor="Red"> 
<h1 style="color:blue">Please provide your details to become a registered user</h1>
<form style="color:blue" action="User_info.php" method="post"> 
User Id: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type="text" name="user_id" value="">
<br><br> 
Password: <input type="password" name="password" value=""> 
<br><br> 
Email Id:  &nbsp <input type="text" name="email_id" value="">
<br><br> 
Phone: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type="text" name="phone_no" value="">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**User_info.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head><title>User Information</title></head>
<body>
<?php

$hostname="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="movie store"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con=mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
if(!$con)
 {
   die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error()); 
 }  
mysql_select_db($db_name,$con);
$id = $_POST['user_id']; 
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email_id'];
$phone= $_POST['phone_no'];
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(user_id,password,email_id,phone_no)        VALUES('$id','$pass','$email','$phone')";
if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{ 
  die('Error: '. mysql_error()); 
}
print_r "1 record inserted";
// close connection 
mysql_close($con);
?> 

<a href="Home.html">Return to Home</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: usage of mysql_* functions is not recommended. Instead you can use mysqli_* functions or pdo_* functions.

Comment: Try removing all `value=""` and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Also this `print_r "1 record inserted";` that should read as `print_r("1 record inserted");` or simply echo or print. What you're using now will produce a parse error which did not show because error reporting is not set/on for your system.

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error on line #29 of User_info.php

use `echo "1 record inserted";` instead of `print_r "1 record inserted";`

MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. [Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Please update your 'User_info.php' with following code as quick MySQLi solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head><title>User Information</title></head>
<body>
<?php

$hostname="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // mysqli username 
$password=""; // mysqli password 
$db_name="movie store"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con=mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
if(!$con)
 {
   die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_error()); 
 }  
mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name);
$id = $_POST['user_id']; 
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email_id'];
$phone= $_POST['phone_no'];
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (user_id,password,email_id,phone_no)        VALUES('$id','$pass','$email','$phone')";
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{ 
  die('Error: '. mysqli_error($con)); 
}
echo "1 record inserted";
// close connection 
mysqli_close($con);
?> 

<a href="Home.html">Return to Home</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I updated my code as per your instructions.Still facing the same problem.Please help me out asap.I need to submit my project tomorrow.

Comment: @Satyakideb What problem you are facing? The above code is working fine for me.